# print error message returned by a class in toast

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, toast

I have a lightning component which is calling another apex class which in turn is calling anotehr apex class by creating its object.

The first class is already returning a value. However, I would also like the error message returned by class 2 and print in a toast message. Is this possible?

Comment: Do share some related code snippet as well, that helps in understanding the problem in more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setCallback

> In your JS controller, use below:

```
    samplecall.setCallback(this, function(Callresp) {
        if (Callresp.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
            helper.showToast('success', Callresp.getReturnValue() );
        } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
            helper.showToast('error', Callresp.getReturnValue() );
        } else if (status === "ERROR") {
            helper.showToast('error', Callresp.getReturnValue() );
        }
    }
```

> In your JS helper, use below:

```
showToast : function(type, message) {
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        "type" : type, "key" : "action:announcement", "message": message
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
}
```

The above toast will show if your apex class has try catch block which returns AuraHandledException.